# Is there any way to override the --help -h argument in python argparse?

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line-arguments, argparse

I am writing a small program which needs to parse an option `-h` using argparse module.

Thus, I have this line in my code: `parser.add_argument("-h")`.

However, when running, python complains:

> argparse.ArgumentError: argument -h/--help: conflicting option
>   string(s): -h

So I wonder if there is any way to override the `-h` provided by default from argparse.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#add-help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @user2357112 I found the answer in argparse doc: https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#add-help

To disable the default `-h`/`--help` flag, we just need to add `add_help=False` into the signature of `ArgumentParser()` like this:

`parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG', add_help=False)`